# Como oculto o elemento de um moldal

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Estou precisando ocultar o título de um moldal quando o usuário clica em um botão para editar, pois este título serve para novo cadastro, gostaria de fazê-lo ficar oculto neste momento.

Descrevendo um pouco melhor a questão:

Se trata de uma aplicação de cadastro para clientes, na aplicação existe um botão para o usuário editar os dados do cliente caso necessário, no momento que o usuário clica em editar, abre o modal com os campos para fazer as alterações necessárias, o título deste modal é "Novo cliente", então eu gostaria de ocultar este título [segue imagem em anexo] já que não faz sentido ele estar lá quando o que está sendo feito no momento é uma edição.

já tentei criar um evento para o botão, mas não serviu.

[[image: imagem da tela]
<sup>clique para visualizar no tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkhHx.jpg)

```js
const limpatitulo = () => {
  document.getElementById('edit').value
  limpatitulo = ("")
}

document.getElementsByClassName('button greem')
  .addEventListener('click', limpatitulo)
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1 class="header-title">Agenda de Pacientes</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <button type="button" class="button blue mobile" id="cadastrarCliente">Cadastrar Pacientes</button>
    <table id="tableClient" class="records">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>E-mail</th>
          <th>Celular</th>
          <th>Cidade</th>
          <th>Data</th>
          <th>horário</th>
          <th>Ação</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="modal" id="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <header class="modal-header">
          <h2>Novo Cliente</h2>
          <span class="modal-close" id="modalClose">&#10006;</span>
        </header>
        <form id="form" class="modal-form">
          <input type="text" id="nome" data-index="new" class="modal-field" placeholder="Nome do Cliente" required>
          <input type="email" id="email" class="modal-field" placeholder="e-mail do Cliente" required>
          <input type="text" id="celular" class="modal-field" placeholder="Celular do Cliente" required>
          <input type="text" id="cidade" class="modal-field" placeholder="Cidade do Cliente" required>
          <input type="text" id="data" class="modal-field" placeholder="Data da consulta" required>
          <input type="text" id="hora" class="modal-field" placeholder="Horário agendado" required>
        </form>
        <footer class="modal-footer">
          <button id="salvar" class="button green">Salvar</button>
          <button id="cancelar" class="button blue">Cancelar</button>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <p>&copy; Todos os direitos reservados</p>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Fiz uma edição colocando mais detalhes do caso.

Answer (score -1):

aqui `document.getElementById('edit').value`é para pegar valor de input...,
agora para selecionar o texto `document.getElementById('edit').innerText`

```
document.getElementsByClassName('button greem')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
     document.getElementById('edit').innerText = " ";
  }
)

-----html-----    

<h2 id="edit" >Novo Cliente</h2>
```

aí para voltar o texto do título, ao salvar as alteracoes ou o cancelamento da mesma você adiciona o título novamente

se nao funcionar, ao invés de você limpar o título, você pode colocar a 'color' do titulo para verde (esse verde que você está usando.)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).